# Solving Exact Equatoins

Tags: calculus

Is the following equation exact ?. I tried to solve but i can't seem to prove that

$$\left[-\,{y \over x^{2}} + 2\sin\left(2x\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x +
\left[{1 \over x} - 2\sin\left(2y\right)\right]\mathrm{d}y
$$

Is in fact an exact equation. I have little knowledge on the topic and i'm trying to educate myself on such.

Comment: First of all: what is it equal to?

Comment: It wasn't equaled to anything the question just stated determine weather the following equatoins are exact and just as i wrote it, is just how it is in the tutorial. and then it went on to say if the equation is exact solve

Comment: If its not equal to anything, how is it an equation?

Comment: i asked a lecturer and he said since the question asked to determine if it is just put it equal to 0 and solve and i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it doesn't equal anything it's not really an equation. However, assuming it is equal to zero (as exact equations are), the way to check if the equation is exact is:

1. Compute the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of the coefficient function of $dx$. That is, compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left [\frac{-y}{x^2}+2\sin(2x)\right ]$.
2. Next, compute the partial derivative with respect to $x$ of the coefficient function of $dy$. That is, compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left [\frac{1}{x}-2\sin(2y)\right ]$.

Now because the coefficient functions have continuous partial derivatives on their domain, if the two partial derivatives you computed are equal, it is an exact equation. I suggest googling exact equations for more information on this, and to see a proof of this. This just shows how to check if the equation is exact, but does not provide steps for solving the equation.